# Which is the best Bitcoin Vanity Address Generator?

Tags: gpu, vanity-address

Can someone please suggest a Bitcoin Vanity Address Generator which can generate at least six characters (ideally case sensitive). It would be even better if the generator could create seven or more characters. I don't mind paying a little but I would prefer the service to be free.

I am looking to create a Vanity Address like `1Bitcoin...` but my system isn't powerful enough. I probably need one or more GPU cards.

There is a post on this topic from several years ago; I'd like something more contemporary if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: I had seen this site but the issue is that it is very outdated. For example, VanitySearch (https://github.com/JeanLucPons/VanitySearch) is probably the most advanced software but is barely mentioned.

Comment: the issue with it being outdated is part of the reason service/product reviews and recommendations are considered to be off topic here. If you know of more up-to-date resources, you should leave an answer on that older question. It is better to update the old question, than to make new questions that ask the same thing.